# Why does Dreamweaver show syntax error for this script line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, dreamweaver

Why does Dreamweaver page using .dwt show syntax error for this script line?

```
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"><\/script>');
</script>
```

It shows syntax error only on a page using the template .dwt file.
Does not show error in the template - only when applied to a page.

Comment: It's probably because the `<script>` tags in the JS code are confusing the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not escaping the first `/` character

```
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery.min.js"> <\/script>');
</script>
```

Should be

```
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js\/jquery.min.js"> <\/script>');
</script>
```

Although you can use `document.createElement('script')` which is less confusing for the parser

```
if(!window.jQuery) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "js/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Yes - RORY, your second answer option resolved the problem. THANK YOU. the if statement fixed it.